# How do you link from a Personal Tab app to a Channel Tab app in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

***Update***

[There's a bug in teams-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/1122#) which is causing `getContext` to return an empty string for `subEntityId`, a required field for deeplinking to an app within a channel within a team.

**Original Question**

I have a requirement to link from a Personal Tab app to a Channel Tab app. Is this possible? If so, how do you do it? I couldn't find any relevant info in the docs.

**Detail**

We have an app which runs in the Channel Tab and the Personal Tab. If you're viewing our app from your Personal Tab, you'll see a list of items which when clicked should navigate to our app in a Channel Tab associated with the clicked item. The channel could be under a different team, but it will be in the same organization, and you are already a member of that team and channel.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this via Deep Linking. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab but specifically here is an example cited in that page:

Link to a configurable tab itself:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fee194/tasklist123?webUrl=https://tasklist.example.com/123&label=Task List 123&context={"channelId": "19:cbe3683f25094106b826c9cada3afbe0@thread.skype"}
```